# Concat a dataframe's value to a dictionary's matching value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bokeh, concatenation

Tangent related to this post: [Customize Bokeh Unemployment Example: Replacing Percentage Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148478/customize-bokeh-unemployment-example-replacing-percentage-value)

Starter code:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import LogColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis6 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure

from bokeh.sampledata.us_counties import data as counties
counties = { code: county for code, county in counties.items() if county["state"] == "tx" }
```

csv data:

[image]

```
I have a dictionary of county names:
{(48, 1): {'name': 'Anderson',
  'detailed name': 'Anderson County, Texas',
  'state': 'tx'}
{(48, 3): {'name': 'Andrews',
  'detailed name': 'Andrews County, Texas',
  'state': 'tx'}

and a dataframe created from a csv file of percentage values:
 {'Anderson': 21.0,
 'Andrews': 28.0,
 'Angelina': 31.0,
 'Aransas': 24.0,
 'Archer': 11.0,
 'Armstrong': 53.0,
 'Atascosa': 27.0,
 'Austin': 30.0,
 'Bailey': 42.0,
 'Bandera': 0.0}
```

I am trying to merge the dataframe's percentage value on the county name in the dictionary.

```
from bokeh.models import LogColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis6 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.us_counties import data as counties
import csv
import pandas as pd

pharmacy_concentration = {}
with open('resources/unemployment.csv', mode = 'r') as infile:
    next(infile)
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
    for row in reader:
        name, concentration = row 
            pharmacy_concentration[name] = float(concentration)

counties = { code: county for code, county in counties.items() if county["state"] == "tx" }
counties = pd.concat(pharmacy_concentration[concentration], on='name', 
how='left', keys='concentration')

counties
```

I receive a keyerror showing the percentage value and can't figure out why.

Expected output:

```
 counties
 {(48, 1): {'name': 'Anderson',
 'detailed name': 'Anderson County, Texas',
 'state': 'tx', 'concentration': 21}
```

Comment: Please include the entire dictionarys (if they are not too big)

Comment: Added. The csv has one unique value for each county name, no duplicates.

Comment: I did not mean the picture, I mean the piece of code, so I can copy and run myself @BoredPando

Comment: Sorry can I add a csv file to my post? I couldn't figure out how to do that. The csv is two columns: name and concentration. If you can get 1 row to concat it should work for the rest. So in a csv file just have column headers: name, concentration, and in the next row: Anderson, 20.

Comment: Try not to add a file, can you do `print(df.head(10))` and copy and paste that in your post? Plus your dictionary is not complete in your post. People cant help you like this.

Comment: I am pulling in the csv file and turning it into a dataframe. The dictionary is from a package that I just import. In theory, the csv file just needs to have 1 row of data be processed correctly and then I can scale it to the full csv file.

Comment: For example, are you trying to update the `concentration` value of `Anderson`? And if yes, what would that value be after the update?

Comment: Yes, essentially take the concentration value of Anderson from the dataframe and listing it in the dictionary for Anderson as ... 'concentration': 21 to then be able to call the concentration value from the dictionary.

Comment: Which is in this case `48` for `Anderson` right?

Comment: (48,1) is the naming convention for the county ID. Each county starts with (48,1) (48,3) (48, 5) etc. The concentration value for Anderson, at least as it's listed above, is 21. But does that mean that the concat needs to be applied to (48,1), not name as I've been trying to do?

Comment: I see that you edited the dictionarys which makes it clearer. Can you add 1 more dicionary or dataframe with `expected output` so I can understand what the result should look like. @BoredPando

Comment: I've added expected outcome

Comment: Does this answer help you? @BoredPando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Tony

```
from bokeh.models import LogColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.us_counties import data as counties
import csv

pharmacy_concentration = {}
with open('resources/unemployment.csv', mode = 'r') as infile:
    reader = [row for row in csv.reader(infile.read().splitlines())]
    for row in reader:
        try:
            county_name, concentration = row
            pharmacy_concentration[county_name] = float(concentration)
        except Exception, error:
            print error, row

counties = { code: county for code, county in counties.items() if county["state"] == 
"tx" }
county_xs = [county["lons"] for county in counties.values()]
county_ys = [county["lats"] for county in counties.values()]
county_names = [county['name'] for county in counties.values()]
# Below is the line of code I was missing to make it work
county_pharmacy_concentration_rates = [pharmacy_concentration[counties[county] 
['name']] for county in counties if counties[county]['name'] in 
pharmacy_concentration]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want to do:

First of all, we get your dictionarys in two dataframes: `county_names` & `csv_data`.
After that I transform them to the right format, but this is probably not necessary for you:

```
county_names = pd.DataFrame({'(48, 1)': {'name': 'Anderson', 'detailed name': 'Anderson County, Texas', 'state': 'tx'}, 
                             '(48, 3)': {'name': 'Andrews', 'detailed name': 'Andrews County, Texas', 'state': 'tx'}}).T.reset_index().rename({'index': 'County_ID'}, axis=1)

print(county_names)
  County_ID           detailed name      name state
0   (48, 1)  Anderson County, Texas  Anderson    tx
1   (48, 3)   Andrews County, Texas   Andrews    tx

 d = {'Anderson': 21.0,
 'Andrews': 28.0,
 'Angelina': 31.0,
 'Aransas': 24.0,
 'Archer': 11.0,
 'Armstrong': 53.0,
 'Atascosa': 27.0,
 'Austin': 30.0,
 'Bailey': 42.0,
 'Bandera': 0.0}

csv_data = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0]).melt(var_name='name', value_name='concentration')
print(csv_data)
        name  concentration
0   Anderson           21.0
1    Andrews           28.0
2   Angelina           31.0
3    Aransas           24.0
4     Archer           11.0
5  Armstrong           53.0
6   Atascosa           27.0
7     Austin           30.0
8     Bailey           42.0
9    Bandera            0.0
```

Now we can merge our data on the `name` column:

```
df_final = pd.merge(county_names, csv_data, on='name')

print(df_final)
  County_ID           detailed name      name state  concentration
0   (48, 1)  Anderson County, Texas  Anderson    tx           21.0
1   (48, 3)   Andrews County, Texas   Andrews    tx           28.0
```

**Note**
You can easily read a `csv file` with pandas, simply use:

```
pd.read_csv(infile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
```